# For a continuous linear functional, is it true that $(Lx)z=(Lz)x $?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For a continuous linear functional $L $, is it true that $(Lx)z=(Lz)x $ ?

I have a claim that for a continuous linear functional defined on a hilbert space $H $, $Lx(z,z)=Lz(x,z) $, where $(,) $ denotes the innner product. I want to know if this follows from the above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is vague. What is $L$?

Comment: it is also assumed to be continuos. This of course implies it is bounded.

Comment: I suspect this is in the proof of the Riesz representation theorem, and that $z$ is specifically chosen, $z\in (\ker L)^\perp$. Is that so?

Comment: $z $ assumed to be orthogonal to the set $\{x:Lx=0 \} $

Comment: so you are right

Comment: In that case, write $x = x_1 + x_2$ with $x_1 \in (\ker L)^\perp$ and $x_2 \in \ker L$. Let $z = \lVert z\rVert\cdot w$, and $x_1 = \pm \lVert x_1\rVert\cdot w$. Then $Lx(z,z) = L(x_1+x_2)(z,z) = L(x_1)(z,z) = \pm \lVert x_1\rVert\cdot\lVert z\rVert Lw(w,z)$, and you can push the scalars in the other position to get $Lx(z,z) = Lz(x_1,z) = Lz(x,z)$.

Comment: So, generally, there is no equality. But in the specific situation in the proof, it holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $Ly = e_1^T y$, $x=e_2,z=e_1$.
Then $(Lx)z = 0$, $(Lz)x = e_2$.